# Error with Eloquent one to many relationship

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-blade

Having issues with a one to many model. I know to access a 1 to many, one needs to itterate a foreach loop. I do this and get blanks.

**Item Model**

```
class Item extends Model

{
protected $table = 'items';
public function offers(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Offer','listing_id');
}
```

**Offer Model**

```
class Offer extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'offers';

    public function item(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Item','listing_id');
    }
}
```

**Item Controller:**

```
public function index()
{
    $user_id = auth()->user()->id;

    $listings = Item::with('offers')->where('user_id','1')->paginate(2);;
    return view('user.dashboard')->with('listings',$listings);
}
```

**VIEW:**

```
@foreach ($listings as $listing)
    {{listing->offer_price}}
@endforeach
```

**So im trying to reference a value from the offer table through     {{listing->offer_price}} but get nothing showing in the view - blanks?** Each item has multiple offers

Answer (score 2):

You need two loops:

```
@foreach ($listings as $listing)
    @foreach ($listing->offers as $offer)
        {{ $offer->price }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```